# Oracle Spatial support QGIS 1.9-0-Master (Ubuntu)

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, oracle-spatial, linux

I just installed QGIS 1.9.0-Master (Build 480) on a Ubuntu virtual machine. I am running/compiled against GDAL/OGR 1.9.2.

Why can't I add Oracle Spatial Layers as I am able to do using QGIS-Master for Windows?

Is this under development for Linux systems or may I missed some package during installation?